# Determining which TTY a program uses

Tags: c, grep, ps

I have a few questions. One, how would one determine the TTY a program uses, and then passing it as a argument to another program?

Also, I'm using the writevt program and i'm sending a string to a TTY device.
It works fine, but doesn't use the carriage return i'm sending it with. So, my question is, how would I do this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

To get the name of the current tty, use `ttyname()`. To send the carriage return character, use `$'\r'`.

`#include <unistd.h>` and `char *tty_name = ttyname(STDIN_FILENO);`

will give you the name of the current tty. See man 3 ttyname for more.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how would I use  ttyname() ?

Comment: Also, thank you for the answer on the carriage return. It's working perfectly.

Comment: One more question. How would I add ttyname() to this code:

Comment: I'm having trouble formatting the code. The "back ticks" don't work.      int apply(void)
{
        char *tty_name = ttyname(STDIN_FILENO);
        system("/usr/sbin/writevt -t ttyname -T new$'\r'");
}

Comment: So, yeah. I'm not sure how to add it to that command line. And this "Add Comment" dialog, doesn't allow me to use the enter key.

Comment: `ttyname(STDIN_FILENO)` will give you the tty that the program runs in. You should use the tty you want to write to.

Comment: `system("/usr/sbin/writevt -t ttyname(STDIN_FILENO) -T new$'\r'");`

Comment: Sorry to pester. But could you repost that code with "back ticks" ??

Comment: Bleh. Same problem. It's unreadable. Would it be too much to ask if you could put it on pastebin?

Comment: If you want to write to the input buffer of another tty, use these headers:

fcntl.h, terimos.h, sys/ioctl.h, unistd.h, string.h.

Use this code:

https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8865545

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't compiling.

Comment: You should have a string `message`, which is whatever you want to write to the input buffer of the tty. And `tty_name` is the name of the tty you want to write to. If it is passed by the command line, like `program /dev/pts/1` it is `argv[1]`.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to pass the tty to `writevt`.

Comment: `char command[255] = "/usr/sbin/writevt -t ";
strcpy(stpcpy(command + 21, tty_name), " -T $\'new\r\'");
system(command);`

Comment: `matrix.c: In function ‘apply’:`
`matrix.c:136:75: error: ‘tty_name’ undeclared (first use in this function)`
` command[255] = "/usr/sbin/writevt -t "; strcpy(stpcpy(command + 21, ``tty_name), `
                                                                     ^
`matrix.c:136:75: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once ``for each function it appears in`
`<builtin>: recipe for target 'matrix.o' failed`
`make: *** [matrix.o] Error 1`

Comment: Getting closer. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. I figured it out. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Ok. I'm having problems now. The `writevt` command seems to work locally, but not remotely. Is there anyway to invoke it remotely?

Comment: And by "locally", I mean literally that. At my own prompt.

Comment: Also, i'm using a `ttysnoop` like program to snoop on the user. For some reason the source isn't running the code when I use it. I created a `printf` to announce my arrival at the array for the code, and it only displays that `printf` when i'm not using that `ttysnoop` like program. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Again.. the users of my BBS aren't able to see the code in action. It's not executing the code for them. I've must of edited and compiled the code at least a hundred times trying to figure this out.

Comment: The problem is with `writevt` somehow. And yes, I have permissions to execute it.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is the code i'm talking about: `char command[255] = "/usr/sbin/writevt -t "; strcpy(stpcpy(command + 21, tty_name), " -T $\'new\r\'"); system(command);`

Comment: If you want to write to the input buffer of another tty, tty_name should be the tty you want to write to, not the name of the tty your program is running in.

Comment: Can you give me some example code? Thanks for your answer, BTW.

Comment: If you will pass name of the tty you want to write to as an argument, use `char command[255] = "/usr/sbin/writevt -t "; strcpy(stpcpy(command + 21, argv[1]), " -T \'new\r\'"); system(command);`.

Comment: What if I don't know the _name_ of the tty?

Comment: If you don't know the name of the tty, how are you going to know which one to write to?

Comment: That's exactly it, I don't know.

Comment: By the way, since you are using string in c, `'\r'` means carriage return. Sorry that I forgot it the first time.

Comment: Not a problem at all.

Comment: Ok. Really stupid question. But, how do I pass the output of "printf $(tty)" to `writevt`?

Comment: `char command[255] = "/usr/sbin/writevt -t "; strcpy(stpcpy(command + 21, argv[1]), " -T \'new\r\'"); system(command);` When you run the program, type `program /dev/tty1` to pass the name of the tty.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>`
`#include <stdlib.h>`
`#include <unistd.h>`
`#include <sys/time.h>`
`#include <sys/types.h>`
`#include <string.h>`
`#include <ctype.h>`

`int main(int argc, char *argv[])`
`{`
`char command[255] = "/usr/sbin/writevt -t "; strcpy(stpcpy(command + 21, 
argv[1]), " -T \'new\r\'"); system(command);`
`}`
:

Comment: Sorry for the format of that code. But, is that correct? Because I get a segfault when running it with no parameters.

Comment: If you run it with no parameters other than the the name of the program, `argc` will be 1, so be sure you check `argc>1` before you use `argv[1]`.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. I know the problem. The code is sending commands to the TTY, not the Pseudo Terminal. Hence, the code is sending commands to my telnet connection, rather than the actual PTS.

Comment: So, my question is this: will `writevt` work with pty devices?

Comment: Ok. It does. Now the question is what do I replace `tty_name` with.

Comment: Ok. I managed to get it working. I'm using the TTYSnoop telnetd server, and it appears to be working. I guess because TTYSnoop puts the screen in "raw" mode.